# SQL - insert multiple tables into a new one, duplicates included

Tags: sql, insert, hana

I've got 6 tables having the same "layout". Means 7 columns with different values. They all start with the COUNT_ID 1 which is why I get an error that inserting them all into one table would cause duplicates....

I need to join them all into one table, even if there might exist duplicates afterwards. Is there any possibility to avoid the error message and insert the duplicate rows nevertheless?

Comment: Don't copy the ID column to the new table, let it generate its own auto-increment ID when you're inserting.

Comment: Or use a new column as the unique ID column in the new table, remove the unique key from the copied ID column.